# iPhone SDK, UIButton on UITableView, delete row if button was pressed

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

I am new in iPhone development and now I have simple question(may be not simple:). I have a `UITableView`, and in that `UITableView` I have for example 5 rows, every row has a `UILabel` and `UIButton`.

What I want to do is to delete one element from the array when my button is pressed. Button I create with tag, but that doesn't work. I do not want use `didSelectRow`; I want to delete  an element from the array only if my button was pressed. (For example, if the third button was pressed I want to  delete the third element of the array. Using the standard delete button does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a custom `UIViewController` to manage each cell (which I highly recommend), simply wire up the button to an `IBAction` and have that method remove the item from whatever data structure supplies the `UITableView` with rows, and then tell the `UITableView` about it.

Failing that, I suppose you could attach a tag to each button, indicating which row it belongs to, and wire them all up to a single `IBAction` in your table-view controller.

Comment: That is, the idea of ​​playing with the `[button tag]` is not a good idea?

Comment: It's perfectly find, and it spares you from creating a custom view controller for each cell. But I find that I almost always end up wanting a customer controller anyway.